# Re-sort TableView Alphabetically

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have tableview that I add cells to via an "add button" and a second view controllers. I currently have the following code setup for my tableview and it sorts the cells alphabetically whenever the app loads. My issue is that when I add a new recipe it does not re-sort automatically. What is the best way to do this? Should my reloadData() be somewhere else? Or perhaps put it in the Segue from view controller back to table view?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        configureView()

        if let savedRecipes = loadRecipes() {
            recipes2 += savedRecipes

            recipes2 = recipes2.sort({current, next in return current.name < next.name})

            recipeList.reloadData()
        }
}
```

Comment: Use [`NSOrderedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `reloadData()` to the `viewWillAppear()` or `viewDidAppear()` methods in your table view controller. That way, whenever you return to the view, it should be showing the most up to date data. For example:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
     super.viewDidAppear(animated)
     reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I ended up putting the sort function and reloadData() in viewWillAppear and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If the recipe is a class on its own you can do it like this:

```
if let savedRecipes = loadRecipes() {
    recipes2 += savedRecipes

    recipes2.sortUsingComparator {
            let r1 = $0 as! Recipe
            let r2 = $1 as! Recipe
            if r1.title < r2.title {
                return .OrderedAscending
            }
            if r1.title == r2.title {
                return .OrderedSame
            }
            return .OrderedDescending
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

This will sort your recipes in ascending order.

Comment: We will need more information on your code though on how you're adding the recipe if its not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ModelAssistant](https://github.com/ssamadgh/ModelAssistant) framework to show recipe objects in tableview. This is a library to mediate between tableView and model. you can set your sort method at the begin of viewcontroller then each new recipe which you add to your model, the model automatically will be sort and also your tableview will be updated too.